# ThrowDisposedException by Autofac while attempting to resolve ScopedLoggerFactory for Cosmos DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, autofac, dbcontext, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using EntityFramework to interact with Cosmos database in my .net core web api application and in certain circumstances it runs into exception which reports the following while attempting to process a transaction:

**Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.**

i am using Autofac for DI so the exception is ultimately thrown by Autofac:

> Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ThrowDisposedException

the registration of cosmos context is pretty standard:

```cs
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
           optionsBuilder
               .UseCosmos(
                   Configuration.GetSection(Constants.Cosmos).GetSection(Constants.AccountEndPoint).Value ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
                   Configuration.GetSection(Constants.Cosmos).GetSection(Constants.AccountKey).Value ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
                   Configuration.GetSection(Constants.Cosmos).GetSection(Constants.DatabaseName).Value ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
                   options => { options.ConnectionMode(ConnectionMode.Direct); }));
```

the use of the context is also not of complicated nature. here is an example of a query that sometimes runs into the exception:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> GetMatchingRecords(params string[] recordIds)
{
    using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    var records = context.Records
        .Where(c => recordIds.Contains(c.RecordId))
        .Select(c => c.RecordId)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();

    return records;
}
```

yet at times when processing this query - it runs into the following

[image]

if i am reading this correctly - it goes to attempt to resolve an instance of a logging service and complains the attempted service is disposed.

I dont do anything to manipulate life-cycle of logging services, i believe it follows default implementation logic inside the middleware.

i cant figure out what is causing this effect. any bright ideas are more than welcome.thank you.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.Internal.ScopedLoggerFactory.Create

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

well, apparently this had to do with the way DI scopes are managed as part of .net core app. in a .net core web api (as a web application) - the scope default setup is per-request. so a scope life-cycle would equal request life-cycle. we had a long running background service which was consuming cosmos and this service had to be re-registered as a scoped background service, which seems to have solved the dependencies issue.